# ZDM Proxy error while connecting application - Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax-zdm-proxy

Getting the below error while connecting to ZDM proxy.

```
time="2023-06-15T00:31:56Z" level=warning msg="Refusing client connection from XX.XXX.XXX.XX:43498 because max clients threshold has been hit (1000)."
time="2023-06-15T00:31:56Z" level=warning msg="Refusing client connection from XX.XXX.XXX.XX:43408 because max clients threshold has been hit (1000)."
time="2023-06-15T00:31:57Z" level=warning msg="Could not find request context for stream id -1 received from TARGET-CONNECTOR. It either timed out or a protocol error occurred."
```

What can be causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the "max clients threshold" has been reached meaning the proxy will stop accepting new client connections.

Default is 500 or 1000 depending on the ZDM version. You can increase it in `vars/proxy_advanced_config_input.yml` and change `zdm_proxy_max_clients_connections`.

https://github.com/datastax/zdm-proxy-automation/blob/f4a0964708b9b73c04e4bf4484c65ac1dd5c829f/ansible/vars/zdm_proxy_advanced_config.yml#LL8C2-L8C35